# i have developed an application using tomcat5.0.28. when i try to execute it it was shoing the following exception

Tags: java, tomcat

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error allocating a servlet instance
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:118)
    org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:160)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:799)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:705)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:577)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:683)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:534)

root cause

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Catalog1 (Unsupported major.minor version 49.0)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass0(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:537)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:123)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1634)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:860)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1307)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1189)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:118)
    org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:160)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:799)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:705)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:577)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:683)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:534)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/5.0.28 logs.

Answer (score 3):

The line `Unsupported major.minor version 49.0` gives the hint that you compiled your code with a java 6 compiler but you use java 5 to run tomcat.